# How to stub with Moq when an object is created from another and a property is changed

Tags: c#, moq

I want to stub a method `GetParametersFromRequest` using Moq. I am only interested in the `Text` property and I want the string `*br*` to be replaced with `\n`.

I want something like this but I don't know how to get the syntax right (if it is possible at all?):

```
myServiceMock.Setup(m => m.GetParametersFromRequest(MyRequest req))
             .Returns( new MyParameters() { Text = req.Text.Replace("*br*","\n") });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
myServiceMock.Setup(m => m.GetParametersFromRequest(It.IsAny<MyRequest>()))
             .Returns((MyRequest req) => new MyParameters() 
                                         { Text = req.Text.Replace("*br*","\n") });
```

or

```
myServiceMock.Setup(m => m.GetParametersFromRequest(It.IsAny<MyRequest>()))
             .Returns<MyRequest>(req => new MyParameters() 
                                         { Text = req.Text.Replace("*br*","\n") });
```

Comment: Or, if you want to match the exact `MyRequest` instance, this also should work: `myServiceMock.Setup(m => m.GetParametersFromRequest(req)).Returns...`

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an error Delegate 'system.func<MyParameters>' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: @Dudute if you have already declared a `req` variable before this line, change your lambda to something like `x => new MyParameters() { Text = x.Text.Replace("*br*","\n") }`

Comment: I don't have another req variable. I also get the error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'MyParameters' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: @Dudute I've updated my answer to make the type of the lambda explicit.  Try that.